# How to make memcached listen on specific/external ip

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, memcached

I am running a **Amazon EC2 instance with an EIP** having successfully installed memcache. I want to set in this machine memcache-ip listening on elastic ip which is attached to the instance.

I tried making change to `/etc/sysconfig/memcached` file and added `OPTIONS="-l my-elastic-ip"`. Restarging the memcacheshow OK.

```
# service memcached restart
Stopping memcached:       [FAILED]
Starting memcached:       [OK]
```

But

```
# service memcached status
# memcached dead but subsys locked
```

`/var/lock/subsys/memcached` and `/etc/lock/subsys/crond` files are empty. File `/var/run/memcached.pid` doesn't even exists. Even killing the process didn't work.

```
# killall -9 memcached
# memcached: no process found
```

Now i m stuck having no idea about what to do. Just to clarify, i am new to **memcached** service.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution. Don't know why/how but instead of writing

```
OPTION="-l ip"
```

i wrote

```
OPTION="ip"
```

and that did worked for me.